# How to get all Cvent events by a registered contact id?

Tags: c#, soap

Given a user id, I'm looking for a way to get all events from Cvent that the user is registered for.

This would be more ideal than getting *all* Cvent events, and filtering out the ones that a user is not registered for.

This is the "search" approach that I have tried:

```
            CvSearch userEventSearch = new CvSearch();
            userEventSearch.Filter = new Filter[1];
            userEventSearch.Filter[0] = new Filter();
            userEventSearch.Filter[0].Operator = CvSearchOperatorType.Includes;

            userEventSearch.Filter[0].Field = <What field to use here?>;
            userEventSearch.Filter[0].Value = <userid>;

            ids = _cventClient.Search(ref _sessionHeader, CvObjectType.Event, userEventSearch).ToList();
```

I'm looking at this list of fields that I can choose from, but I don't believe any of them pertain to the information that I want:
http://tek-works.com/cvent-api-event-fields-and-their-format/

Additionally, there is a "retrieve" approach that might be useful, but I don't believe this will be very useful to me:

```
CvObject[] objects = _cventClient.Retrieve(ref _sessionHeader, CvObjectType.<What CvObjectType to use here?>, new[] { <userid> });
```

I'm trying to figure out if there is a work-around to get the information that I need. (e.g. do I need to retrieve Registrations and do some work with them to get the events that I need?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

For posterity I figured it out. Perhaps this will help others in the future. You must first search for and retrieve all Registrations for a user.

Once you've done that, you can use those Registrations to obtain the EventIds:

```
            // First search for all registrations for this user using their contact id (SourceId).
            CvSearch userRegistrationSearch = new CvSearch();
            userRegistrationSearch.Filter = new Filter[1];
            userRegistrationSearch.Filter[0] = new Filter();
            userRegistrationSearch.Filter[0].Operator = CvSearchOperatorType.Includes;

            userRegistrationSearch.Filter[0].Field = "SourceId";
            userRegistrationSearch.Filter[0].Value = registeredContactId;

            var registrationIds = _cventClient.Search(ref _sessionHeader, CvObjectType.Registration, userRegistrationSearch);

            // Using the results of that search, retrive all the registrations from Cvent
            var registrations = _cventClient.Retrieve(ref _sessionHeader, CvObjectType.Registration, registrationIds).ToList().ConvertAll(items => (Registration)items);

            // Return all the event ids from these registrations.
            return registrations.Select(r => r.EventId).ToList();
```

Comment: I ended up having to change `CvSearchOperatorType.Includes` to `CvSearchOperatorType.Equals` but otherwise this worked great for me. Thank you!